# CSS animation rotate then wiggle SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have an SVG compass with an arrow in it. I want to be able to add a class to the arrow and have it rotate a certain degree then stay there and wiggle.
I have the rotation and wiggle working just not together. Not sure how to combine the two so they work together. Here is my code:

```css
div {
  max-width: 40%;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #505050;
  stroke-width: 4.11;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #808080;
  stroke-width: 2.57;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #505050;
}

.st3 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.st4 {
  fill: none;
}


/* Fill Colors */

.green {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.dgreen {
  fill: rgba(12, 140, 0, 0.5);
}

.red {
  fill: rgba(255, 42, 0, 0.5);
}

.dred {
  fill: rgba(140, 23, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Arrow */

#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: wiggle;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Rotations */

.north#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.northEast#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.west#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.southWest#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.south#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.southWest#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.west#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.northWest#arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}


/* Wiggle Animation */


/* safari and chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}


/* firefox */

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 116.3 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 116.3 144;" xml:space="preserve">
    
    <title>compass</title>
    <line id="N" class="st0" x1="58.2" y1="31.3" x2="58.2" y2="49.6"/>
    <line id="NW" class="st1" x1="18.5" y1="46.1" x2="31.4" y2="59"/>
    <line id="W" class="st0" x1="3.6" y1="85.7" x2="21.9" y2="85.7"/>
    <line id="SW" class="st1" x1="18.3" y1="125.5" x2="31.3" y2="112.5"/>
    <line id="S" class="st0" x1="58" y1="140.3" x2="58" y2="122"/>
    <line id="SE" class="st1" x1="97.7" y1="125.6" x2="84.8" y2="112.6"/>
    <line id="E" class="st0" x1="113.4" y1="85.9" x2="95.1" y2="85.9"/>
    <line id="NE" class="st1" x1="97.8" y1="46.2" x2="84.9" y2="59.1"/>
    <path id="compass" class="st2" d="M69.6,28.8c6.7-6.3,7-16.9,0.7-23.6s-16.9-7-23.6-0.7s-7,16.9-0.7,23.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7
     c-31.5,6.3-51.9,37-45.6,68.5s37,51.9,68.5,45.6c31.5-6.3,51.9-37,45.6-68.5C110.6,51.4,92.6,33.4,69.6,28.8z M58.2,6.5
     c5.6,0,10.2,4.6,10.2,10.2H48C48,11.1,52.6,6.5,58.2,6.5z M58.2,138.3c-29,0-52.5-23.5-52.5-52.5s23.5-52.5,52.5-52.5
     c29,0,52.5,23.5,52.5,52.5c0,0,0,0,0,0C110.6,114.8,87.1,138.3,58.2,138.3z"/>
    <path id="inner_compass" class="st2" d="M58.2,130.8c-24.9,0-45.2-20.2-45.2-45.2s20.2-45.2,45.2-45.2c24.9,0,45.2,20.2,45.2,45.1
     c0,0,0,0,0,0C103.3,110.6,83.1,130.8,58.2,130.8z M58.2,43.8c-23.1,0-41.9,18.8-41.9,41.9s18.8,41.9,41.9,41.9s41.9-18.8,41.9-41.9
     C100.1,62.6,81.3,43.8,58.2,43.8L58.2,43.8z"/>
    <g id="NNW" class="st3">
     <path id="nnwPie" class="st4 green" d="M57.9,27.7v58.2l-41-41C27.8,33.9,42.5,27.7,57.9,27.7z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="WNW" class="st3">
     <path id="wnwPie" class="st4 dgreen" d="M57.9,85.8H0.2v-0.2c0-15.3,6-30,16.8-40.8L57.9,85.8z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="WSW">
     <path id="wswPie" class="st4" d="M57.9,85.8l-40.8,40.8c-10.8-10.8-16.9-25.5-17-40.8H57.9z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SSW">
     <path id="sswPie" class="st4" d="M57.9,85.8v57.8c-15.3,0-30-6.2-40.8-17L57.9,85.8z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SSE">
     <path id="ssePie" class="st4 red" d="M99,126.9c-10.8,10.8-25.5,16.8-40.8,16.8H58V85.8L99,126.9z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ESE">
     <path id="esePie" class="st4 dred" d="M116.2,85.8c0,15.4-6.2,30.2-17.2,41l-41-41H116.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ENE">
     <path id="enePie" class="st4" d="M116.2,85.7v0.2H57.9l41.2-41.2C110.1,55.5,116.2,70.3,116.2,85.7z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="NNE">
     <path id="nnePie" class="st4" d="M99.1,44.6L57.9,85.8V27.7h0.2C73.5,27.6,88.3,33.7,99.1,44.6z"/>
    </g>
    <polygon id="arrow" class="st2 west" points="78.4,105.3 80.2,107.1 79.1,108.3 77.2,106.4 75.5,109.7 74.1,108.6 75.9,105.1 75.1,104.3 
     73.3,107.7 71.9,106.6 73.8,103 72.9,102.1 71.2,105.6 69.8,104.5 71.7,100.9 63.5,92.7 63.5,92.7 41.5,70.7 41.4,70.8 39,74.3 
     34.5,62.5 46.3,67.1 42.5,69.5 64.6,91.6 65.2,92.1 72.9,99.8 76.5,98 77.6,99.5 74.1,101.1 74.9,101.9 78.6,100 79.7,101.4 
     76.2,103.1 75.9,102.9 77.1,104 80.8,102.3 81.9,103.8 "/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chain animations together and use a delay between them so one plays after the other has finished.

You were previously using a transition and then an animation which are two separate things. Also browser prefixes are now pretty redundant for animations, I personally would use the non-prefixed syntax.

Here is one example where the arrow moves to the south and then wiggles, you will need to add in the others:

**Example CSS**

```
.wrap:hover #arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: spinSouth, wiggleSouth;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
}

/* Spin south Animation */
@keyframes spinSouth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
}

/* Wiggle Animation */
@keyframes wiggleSouth {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(220deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5cn9sm99/

Comment: Thanks that put me on the right track. Appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a shorter solution with the code you already have. You could wrap your arrow in an arrow container like this:

```
<g id="arrowContainer">    
  <polygon id="arrow" class="st2 west" points="78.4,105.3 80.2,107.1 79.1,108.3 77.2,106.4 75.5,109.7 74.1,108.6 75.9,105.1 75.1,104.3 
    73.3,107.7 71.9,106.6 73.8,103 72.9,102.1 71.2,105.6 69.8,104.5 71.7,100.9 63.5,92.7 63.5,92.7 41.5,70.7 41.4,70.8 39,74.3 
    34.5,62.5 46.3,67.1 42.5,69.5 64.6,91.6 65.2,92.1 72.9,99.8 76.5,98 77.6,99.5 74.1,101.1 74.9,101.9 78.6,100 79.7,101.4 
  76.2,103.1 75.9,102.9 77.1,104 80.8,102.3 81.9,103.8 "/>
</g>
```

Then add this styles to center the pivot point of the container:

```
#arrowContainer{  transform-origin: 50% 50%;  }
```

Now replace the Rotations to target the arrowContainer and use Javascript or jQuery to add the classes you already created. Here is the full code.

```js
var changeDirection = function changeClass(myClass){
    $('#compass').attr("class", myClass);
}
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #505050;
  stroke-width: 4.11;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #808080;
  stroke-width: 2.57;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #505050;
}

.st3 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.st4 {
  fill: none;
}


/* Fill Colors */

.green {
  fill: rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.dgreen {
  fill: rgba(12, 140, 0, 0.5);
}

.red {
  fill: rgba(255, 42, 0, 0.5);
}

.dred {
  fill: rgba(140, 23, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Arrow */
#arrowContainer{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
#arrow {
  transform-origin: 50% 59.7%;
  animation-name: wiggle;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Rotations */

.north #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.northEast #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.east #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.southEast #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.south #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.southWest #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.west #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.northWest #arrowContainer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}


/* Wiggle Animation */


/* safari and chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes compass {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

/* firefox */

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
}

/* Button Styles */
.buttons{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<button onclick="changeDirection('north')">North</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('northEast')">NorthEast</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('east')">East</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('southEast')">South East</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('south')">South</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('southWest')">South West</button>
  
  <button onclick="changeDirection('west')">West</button>
  <button onclick="changeDirection('northWest')">North West</button>
</div>
<div id="compass" class="addClassHere">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 116.3 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 116.3 144;" xml:space="preserve">
    
    <title>compass</title>
    <line id="N" class="st0" x1="58.2" y1="31.3" x2="58.2" y2="49.6"/>
    <line id="NW" class="st1" x1="18.5" y1="46.1" x2="31.4" y2="59"/>
    <line id="W" class="st0" x1="3.6" y1="85.7" x2="21.9" y2="85.7"/>
    <line id="SW" class="st1" x1="18.3" y1="125.5" x2="31.3" y2="112.5"/>
    <line id="S" class="st0" x1="58" y1="140.3" x2="58" y2="122"/>
    <line id="SE" class="st1" x1="97.7" y1="125.6" x2="84.8" y2="112.6"/>
    <line id="E" class="st0" x1="113.4" y1="85.9" x2="95.1" y2="85.9"/>
    <line id="NE" class="st1" x1="97.8" y1="46.2" x2="84.9" y2="59.1"/>
    <path id="compass" class="st2" d="M69.6,28.8c6.7-6.3,7-16.9,0.7-23.6s-16.9-7-23.6-0.7s-7,16.9-0.7,23.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7
     c-31.5,6.3-51.9,37-45.6,68.5s37,51.9,68.5,45.6c31.5-6.3,51.9-37,45.6-68.5C110.6,51.4,92.6,33.4,69.6,28.8z M58.2,6.5
     c5.6,0,10.2,4.6,10.2,10.2H48C48,11.1,52.6,6.5,58.2,6.5z M58.2,138.3c-29,0-52.5-23.5-52.5-52.5s23.5-52.5,52.5-52.5
     c29,0,52.5,23.5,52.5,52.5c0,0,0,0,0,0C110.6,114.8,87.1,138.3,58.2,138.3z"/>
    <path id="inner_compass" class="st2" d="M58.2,130.8c-24.9,0-45.2-20.2-45.2-45.2s20.2-45.2,45.2-45.2c24.9,0,45.2,20.2,45.2,45.1
     c0,0,0,0,0,0C103.3,110.6,83.1,130.8,58.2,130.8z M58.2,43.8c-23.1,0-41.9,18.8-41.9,41.9s18.8,41.9,41.9,41.9s41.9-18.8,41.9-41.9
     C100.1,62.6,81.3,43.8,58.2,43.8L58.2,43.8z"/>
    <g id="NNW" class="st3">
     <path id="nnwPie" class="st4 green" d="M57.9,27.7v58.2l-41-41C27.8,33.9,42.5,27.7,57.9,27.7z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="WNW" class="st3">
     <path id="wnwPie" class="st4 dgreen" d="M57.9,85.8H0.2v-0.2c0-15.3,6-30,16.8-40.8L57.9,85.8z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="WSW">
     <path id="wswPie" class="st4" d="M57.9,85.8l-40.8,40.8c-10.8-10.8-16.9-25.5-17-40.8H57.9z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SSW">
     <path id="sswPie" class="st4" d="M57.9,85.8v57.8c-15.3,0-30-6.2-40.8-17L57.9,85.8z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SSE">
     <path id="ssePie" class="st4 red" d="M99,126.9c-10.8,10.8-25.5,16.8-40.8,16.8H58V85.8L99,126.9z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ESE">
     <path id="esePie" class="st4 dred" d="M116.2,85.8c0,15.4-6.2,30.2-17.2,41l-41-41H116.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ENE">
     <path id="enePie" class="st4" d="M116.2,85.7v0.2H57.9l41.2-41.2C110.1,55.5,116.2,70.3,116.2,85.7z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="NNE">
     <path id="nnePie" class="st4" d="M99.1,44.6L57.9,85.8V27.7h0.2C73.5,27.6,88.3,33.7,99.1,44.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="arrowContainer">
    
    <polygon id="arrow" class="st2 west" points="78.4,105.3 80.2,107.1 79.1,108.3 77.2,106.4 75.5,109.7 74.1,108.6 75.9,105.1 75.1,104.3 
     73.3,107.7 71.9,106.6 73.8,103 72.9,102.1 71.2,105.6 69.8,104.5 71.7,100.9 63.5,92.7 63.5,92.7 41.5,70.7 41.4,70.8 39,74.3 
     34.5,62.5 46.3,67.1 42.5,69.5 64.6,91.6 65.2,92.1 72.9,99.8 76.5,98 77.6,99.5 74.1,101.1 74.9,101.9 78.6,100 79.7,101.4 
      76.2,103.1 75.9,102.9 77.1,104 80.8,102.3 81.9,103.8 "/>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```